# directory C:/user name/folder/appName 'does not contain a Gradle build

Tags: flutter, dart, build.gradle

Directory 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Flutter\banking_app' does not contain a Gradle build.

I am facing this issue every time I import any project. Even if I have created new projects but when I try to import them next time then this issue appears.

The error states:
**directory C:/user name/folder/appName 'does not contain a Gradle build.

[image: Please check the screenshothere]

Hopefully, you can understand what is the main problem with it.

Found no any valid solution yet.

Comment: try syncing the gradle

Comment: Hello there, I also tried this but same the error :(

Comment: has this been solved yet?

Answer (score 2):

1. Active Tool(Gradle) in IntelliJ IDEA.
2. Unlink Gradle Project(Delete)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install Gradle

```
 brew install gradle
```

And probably get a SDK version, one that fits best your project. You can find it in settings/Languages & Frameworks/Android SDK.

Answer (score -1):

In terminal project you can try type gradle init

Comment: Also tried this, but nothing found workable :(